Animating a FunctionGraph in manim with respect to a parameter
I have to animate a FunctionGraph in manim with respect to a parameter a. Now, this is not a parametric function and ParametricFunction will not work for me. I am looking for something similar to the variable slider feature on Desmos.
The function that I am looking to plot is
y = x ** 2 / 3 + (3.3 - x ** 2) ** 1 / 2 * np.sin(a * PI * x)

where I would like to vary a to create the animation.
A very rudimentary approach I can imagine is to simply use a for loop and range() as shown below,
def construct(self):
    for a in range (7, 15, 0.1):
        heart = Function Graph(
            lambda x: x ** 2 / 3 + (3.3 - x ** 2) ** 1 / 2 * np.sin(a * PI * x),
            x_range = [-1.8, 1.8],
        )

        self.add(heart)
        self.wait(1/3)
        self.remove(heart)

But I am hoping for something better designed and better interpolated than my 30 frames per second animation. Is there a better way of dealing with this, and are there any in-built functions for handling this?

as for me your for-loop looks good designed and I wouldn't search anything else.

maybe better create minimal working code so we could simply copy and run it - to see interpolation. But if all code works with 30FPS then running something faster can makes no sense. maybe you need only option manim --fps 60 ... when render all animation.
